# Angular $http request works strange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

Why **$http** service finishes the request and then loads the JSON data?

[Minimal code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/S26o5BItfNaGoESZXc49?p=preview)

```
var vm = this;
$http
  .get("/getData")
  .then(function (data) {
    // promise is resolved but I still don't have access to the data
    vm.data = data;
  });
```

When I test this in chrome browser I see the following:

- pending request ( "/getData" )
- **Status Code**: 200 ( the request finishes )
- in **preview** or **response** tab no response data is available
- at the bottom of the **google inspector**: 1.5 MB (response data ) transferred
- json response data is available after 5 seconds

When the request finishes (and shows **Status 200 OK**) I expect to have access to the response data (which is **not downloaded** yet).

---

**Conclusion**

Even if the request finishes with **code status 200 OK** and my promise is ready, I still have to wait 5 seconds for the data to be transferred.

Comment: Can you provide a testable example? Never had this issue, so might be your implementation that's causing it.

Comment: from the 5 sec response it is issue from backend i guess , but i wonder how did you know it takes 5 seconds ??
please provide a plunker

Comment: what are you doing? downloading from backend?    and btw what is `this` here? you can try with `$scope.postData = data.data`

Comment: `this.data = data` could be wrong, because it refers to the `function` scope, which I think is not what you want.

Comment: @Hinrich yes, that doesn't matters anyway

Comment: @pro.mean getting some data, doesn't matter

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam can't provide example because of the now free rest api let's me to send 1300 json records ...

Comment: it's matters whether you are downloading or fetching the data only

Comment: @pro.mean so, your suggestion is to check the backend implementation for this rest service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For angular `$http` service, network tab shows two kinds of requests for a single API call of which one is API with `OPTION` method call. `OPTION` method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval. The second one may be your actual API call. You can check the network tab. This is `$http` service default behaviour.

Comment: @que1326 : please check if network tab shows two calls for single API call and of which one is OPTION method.